# Making a Homebrew Formula

Tags: java, macos, dependencies, homebrew

I am trying to make a `brew` formula for a compiler specific to my university.

The package doesn't have a `./configure`, `make`, `make install` way of installing. Instead it just asks you to have `java` and `javac` installed and do the following:

- Download a folder containing the files: `gcl`, `gclc` and `gcl.jar`
- `cd <folder>/`
- `chmod +x gclc gcl`
- `echo export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$PWD >> ~/.bashrc`

So I don't know how to handle the `CLASSPATH` part in the formula, neither the part of copying the binaries into `/usr/local/bin` *(where hombrew saves the binaries)*.

What I have so far is this:

```
require "formula"

class Gacela < Formula
  homepage "http://wiki.lal.labf.usb.ve/GacelaWiki"
  url "http://ldc.usb.ve/~09-10285/GaCeLa.tar.gz"
  sha1 ""

  def install
    system "chmod +x ./gcl ./gclc"
    system "ln -s ./gcl #{bin}/gcl"
    system "ln -s ./gclc #{bin}/gclc"
    system "echo export GACELA_PATH=$PWD >> ~/.bash_profile"
    system "echo export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$PWD >> ~/.bash_profile"
  end

  # test do
  #   system "false"
  # end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

At least the part of copying can be done with

```
bin.install('gcl')
bin.install('gclc')
```

which will automatically gice them +x permissions, so you can skip the chmod commands. As the files seem to be just shell scripts it might be best to patch them in order to include the correct classpath.

Comment: Thanks, I actually filed an issue in the GitHub repo and solved it: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/27340